# netbeans - Textfield accepting only doubles

Tags: java, netbeans, special-characters, jtextfield

Thank you for your time. I want to code my text-field that only accept double. I have code. That is working well for Digit, Letter etc... But i am new to programming. So i can not able to make it for only double. Exactly i want to allow like this values:

**10.25**

**1.345**

etc...

This is my cool code:

```
private void priceInKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
char enter = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(!(Character.isDigit(enter) ||(enter == KeyEvent.VK_BACKSPACE) || enter == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
        getToolkit().beep();
        evt.consume();
    }
}
```

I want only edit this code and make my program. It will easy to my next step.

Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse double from string, if error occurs it means that string represents wrong double value.

```
public boolean isDouble(String value) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(value);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Parsing doubles over and over again would take more time and more memory than checking a regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the char inputted over and over again, try to get the current text, and check if it matches a certain regular expression:

- If you're trying to capture both ints and doubles, use `\d+((\.\d+)?)`.

  - \d+ Means you're matching 1 or more digits, and (\.\d+) means a dot followed by 1 or more digits. The question mark means it's optional.
- If you're trying to capture doubles only, use `\d+\.\d+`.

  - \d+ means 1 or more digit, and . is a dot (in regex, it has to be prefixed with a `\` because just a regular dot means any character.

To check wether or not your text matches a regular expression, use:

```
String str = ...; //Get the text from the textbox
boolean isDouble = str.matches("Your regular expression here!");
```

**NOTE:** When trying to put the `\` character in a string in java, type `\\` instead, so `\d+((\.\d+)?)` becomes `\\d+((\\.\\d+)?)` when typed in java.

In your code, inside the event, instead of:

```
char enter = evt.getKeyChar();
if(!(Character.isDigit(enter) ||(enter == KeyEvent.VK_BACKSPACE) || enter == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
    getToolkit().beep();
    evt.consume();
}
```

Use:

```
if(yourTextField.getText().matches("\\d+\\.\\d+")){
    //Do whatever
}
```

**EDIT:** Also, regarding to your method's name (`Price_inKeyTyped`)I assume you don't know java naming conventions.

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

*Taken from oracle - Click [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)*

Comment: @Oldmax Added. even though I'm not really for spoonfeeding, so please try to actually understand what I wrote before you copy and paste if you do. Hope I helped!

Comment: Thank you  NonameSL, Yea i am new to java. I am Learning with your comments. Yes your code is working. But the problem is it allowing Strings. I do not need to put Letters in to my textfield. Your code allowing like this inputs: 2.aaa, b.90 etc... I only need like this: 50.25, 10.75, 1.50 Exactly like: Rs. 1.50, 1.50$ etc... Hope you got it. I used this textfiled for store some price on database. My interface allowed double values. That is i want.  Please look this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9B5ZgItFxNA it is about it. Thank you for your time. Hope you will fix it.